# Create VPN server using the Ubuntu VPS

Tags: server, vpn

I have an Ubuntu (Debian) VPS in USA, NOW want to make up VPN service on it.
Can you help me to handle it, please.

- Which program surplussed me for.
- What about Socks!. [I need it too]
- How can I install it.
- Which account manager is better then for accounting.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For this instructions we assume your virtual server has IP: 83.170.XXX.XXX (replace with the real IP everywhere).

Then login via SSH as root

```
ssh root@83.170.XXX.XXX
```

Following these commands and instructions, update Ubuntu:

```
apt-get update 
apt-get upgrade 
apt-get install pptpd
```

Edit the file `/etc/pptpd.conf` and add:

```
localip 192.168.0.1 
remoteip 192.168.0.2-254
```

Insert the name servers in `/etc/ppp/pptpd-options`:

```
ms-dns 8.8.8.8
ms-dns 8.8.4.4
```

Create two test users in `/etc/ppp/chap-secrets`

```
user1 pptpd password1 * 
user2 pptpd password2 *
```

Setup routing for VPN server in `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

Now edit `/etc/rc.local` (insert before exit 0 and replace 83.XXX.XXX.XXX with your VPS IP number):

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/24 ! -d 192.168.0.0/24 -j SNAT --to-source 83.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

Restart and we are done.

```
shutdown -r now
```

Now you can log in with VPN over PPTP with either of the credentials you created before:

- user1/password1
- user2/password2

[Source](http://wiki.vps.net/os-related-issues/other-services/how-to-vps-as-a-vpn-server/)

[This video will help you also](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wjUKo3lsR-k)

[See this also](http://vpsnoc.com/blog/2010/01/how-to-install-openvpn-on-a-debianubuntu-vps-instantly/)

Comment: I have tried using Windows PPTP connection to my VPS server after following those procedures. Windows kept giving me this error: Error 619: A connection to the remote computer could not be established, so the port used for the connection was closed.