# VPN on Ubuntu 11.10 VPS

Tags: vpn, pptp

I have been trying to install a VPN onto my VPS. 
I have followed the Tutorial [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/199286/create-vpn-server-using-the-ubuntu-vps) , However have had trouble getting it to work.
Can somebody please tell me how i should go about installing this VPN.
Kind Regards
Ryan

Comment: would you please specify which vps service provider you are using ...

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response. I am using http://virpus.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Virpus said they support PPTP VPN on their OpenVZ VPS , and you need to request them to **enable** it .

**[Virpus Networks](http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=1001005#post7140178)**

**hotsnow**

Do U-Basic VPS support TUN/TAP and PPP Device? I want use PPTP VPN, thank you.

**Virpus Networks**

Yes, however, you'd need to request this be activated via our support department.

Comment: Haha, i had asked them to enable TUN/TAP but forgot about PPP.
Thanks for the help