# How to install a PPTP VPN without a localip?

Tags: vpn, pptp

As the title says, how can I set up a PPTP VPN without a localip? What I mean by this is I have an external ip (69.164.212.xxx), but no local ip as this is a server hosted in a datacenter, each VPS has it's own IP.

I'm currently running Ubuntu 12.04, but I can easily switch over to whatever version is required for this. And for anyone wondering, my server is a VPS hosted by Linode.

Comment: Possible Duplicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/294120/how-to-debug-and-fix-pptp-vpn-client-connection/295309#295309

Comment: Possible Duplicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/119534/

Comment: Have you requested them to add pptp module on your vps ?

Comment: @Qasim, no that is not possible as I understand it, the point of a VPS is that I have complete root control of the VPS, and thus it is my job to install what I want installed.

Comment: Just do what i say, open a ticket to linode VPS, and asked them " Have you added PPTP module on my VPS "

Comment: @Qasim, there reply was about what I expected

"Linode does not install any software or modules on Linodes once they are deployed, and our base images have very basic package groups with no extras that aren't needed for a basic Linux system.

I hope this clears things up."

So I need to install and configure it myself, which I have done many times, but everytime I get that same error.

Comment: @scaru  I have purchased 3 to 4 vps in last 6 months from myhosting and servermania, every time i have to request them to add pptp module to my vps....so thats the reason...you can also check my answer http://askubuntu.com/questions/290384/vpn-on-ubuntu-11-10-vps/290448#290448, let me check with linode ...i have deleted my answer & i will update ASAP...

Comment: Have a look http://akensai.com/linode-vpn/

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the servers real external IP as its localip for the VPN.

If you think that won't work, or if it doesn't seem to be working, please clarify your question.  Maybe add a diagram of how you want it set up.

Answer (score 0):

You can get complete details from here !

http://wiki.hidemyass.com/Tutorials:Using_local_PPTP_server_as_VPN_router_alternative

http://www.bestvpnservice.com/pptp-vpn-service.php